# Split a string inside array , then take it out of inner array to become an item of external array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, ecmascript-6

FROM HERE: (this array is call response)

```
 [
    { "DAY": 20190323,"NAME": "BTA130", "STREAMNAME": "Instant Purification, Pentatone  A/B , This is a drill"},
    { "DAY": 20190324,"NAME": "BTA130", "STREAMNAME": "Instant Purification, Pentatone  A/B , This is a drill"},
    { "DAY": 20190325,"NAME": "BTA130", "STREAMNAME": "Instant Purification, Pentatone  A/B , This is a drill"},
    { "DAY": 20190326,"NAME": "BTA130", "STREAMNAME": "Instant Purification, Pentatone  A/B , This is a drill"},
    { "DAY": 20190327,"NAME": "BTA130", "STREAMNAME": "Instant Purification, Pentatone  A/B , This is a drill"},
 ]
```

TO HERE:

```
[
     [20190323, "Instant Purification", "Pentatone A/B" , "This is a drill"],
     [20190324, "Instant Purification", "Pentatone A/B" , "This is a drill"],
     [20190325, "Instant Purification", "Pentatone A/B" , "This is a drill"],
     [20190326, "Instant Purification", "Pentatone A/B" , "This is a drill"],
     [20190327, "Instant Purification", "Pentatone A/B" , "This is a drill"]
]
```

SO I DID:

```
const yearDays = res.map(x => x['YEAR_DAY']);
const streams = res.map(x => x['STREAMNAME']);

const labeler = yearDays.map((v, i) => {return [v, String(streams[i]).split(/\s*(?:,|$)\s*/)]; });
```

INSTEAD I'VE GOT: (which is sorta close but not really)

```
[20190323, ["Instant Purification", "Pentatone A/B" , "This is a drill"]
[20190324, ["Instant Purification", "Pentatone A/B" , "This is a drill"]
[20190325, ["Instant Purification", "Pentatone A/B" , "This is a drill"]
...
```

How can I get all the elements out of the  inner array and make them part of the outer array ?

Comment: How so @MaheerAli?

Comment: maybe I've copied it wrong. hold on

Comment: Again, how so? It's a string with commas.

Comment: @JackBashford Sorry mate my mistake, The code is fine.

Comment: I've updated the array and put commas at the end. also validated it on a json validator. should be good now

Comment: @brohymn what is `streams`? Please post all your code.

Comment: @JackBashford UPDATED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map()` and return new array with `DAY` property and splited `STREAMNAME` property. You should use [Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to make the array flat.

```js
let arr = [
    { "DAY": 20190323,"NAME": "BTA130", "STREAMNAME": "Instant Purification, Pentatone  A/B , This is a drill"},
    { "DAY": 20190324,"NAME": "BTA130", "STREAMNAME": "Instant Purification, Pentatone  A/B , This is a drill"},
    { "DAY": 20190325,"NAME": "BTA130", "STREAMNAME": "Instant Purification, Pentatone  A/B , This is a drill"},
    { "DAY": 20190326,"NAME": "BTA130", "STREAMNAME": "Instant Purification, Pentatone  A/B , This is a drill"},
    { "DAY": 20190327,"NAME": "BTA130", "STREAMNAME": "Instant Purification, Pentatone  A/B , This is a drill"},
 ]
 
 let res = arr.map(({DAY,STREAMNAME})=>[DAY,...STREAMNAME.split(', ')])
 
 console.log(res)
```

Comment: Excellent. I know I wasnt seeing something , thanks

Comment: @brohymn The thing you were missing was using spread operator.